# Find a string at the beginning of all lines in a file and save to another file

Tags: windows, batch, csv, findstr

I have tried quite a few options with no luck for this task. I would really like to do this as batch file but my attempts fail to get the desired result.

I have tried a lot of different commands with `findstr` but it seems to write out everything in one big line plus make the characters look strange at times.

**One of my failed attempts**

```
findstr /i /n "\<JH*\>" c:\Users\Desktop\split\file.txt > JH.tx
```

I need to find all entries in one `.csv` file that starts with "**JH**" and save only those to new `.csv` file.

**Sample CSV file to search**

```
JH009,20,John May.pdf
PB184,90,Chicken.pdf
JH024,10,Fred Walmsley.pdf
JH080,12,Now Call.pdf 
PB091,10,Mice.pdf
PB884,1040,Cat Order.pdf
```

**Expected result in new output CSV file**

```
JH009,20,John May.pdf 
JH024,10,Fred Walmsley.pdf
JH080,12,Now Call.pdf
```

Comment: Can you provide examples of what you've tried already, and what the output was?  It will help us avoid suggesting things you've already tried, and may help us identify why it's not working for you.  PS: While you say you want to do this in Batch, PowerShell has CSV handling stuff built into it, you should try it. :)

Comment: findstr /i /n "\<JH*\>" c:\Users\Desktop\split\file.txt > JH.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Findstr](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) command with the `/B` switch to tell it to match the pattern at the beginning of the lines in the file you are searching. If the pattern is not to be case sensitive then use the `/I` switch or else simply omit it from the command for a case sensitive pattern match of the string.

**Syntax**

```
FindStr /I /B "JH" "c:\Users\Desktop\split\file.txt" > "JH.csv"
```

---

**File Searched**

```
JH009,20,John May.pdf
PB184,90,Chicken.pdf
JH024,10,Fred Walmsley.pdf
JH080,12,Now Call.pdf
PB091,10,Mice.pdf
PB884,1040,Cat Order.pdf
```

**FindStr Command Output**

```
JH009,20,John May.pdf
JH024,10,Fred Walmsley.pdf
JH080,12,Now Call.pdf
```

---

### Further Resources

- [Findstr](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html)
- `FindStr /?`

  > ```
  > /B         Matches pattern if at the beginning of a line.   
  > /I         Specifies that the search is not to be case-sensitive.
  > ```
  >
  > ---
  >
  > ```
  > Example: FindStr /I /B "<String>" "<FileToSearch>" > "<OutputFile>"
  > ```
- [Redirection](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html)

Comment: HI I JUST TESTED COPIED AND PASTED YOUR SYNTAX AND IT CREATED A .CSV FILE BUT IT WAS EMPTY?